# how to get data from database in wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

Hello i want to get the data from database and put in on pages i write this code but it didnt work. how can i get the data from sql to be appear in the page thank for helping

```
<?php    
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb wp_ ."sheet1";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE Course='Filipino' ORDER BY Lastname";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql);
?>

Data should be appear in this table
<table id="passers_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><center>Course</center></th>
<th><center>Student Number</center></th>
<th><center>Name</center></th>
<th><center>LinkedIn Account</center></th>
<th><center>Email Address</center></th>
<th><center>Nationality</center></th>
<th><center>City</center></th>
<th><center>Country</center></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>$print->;Course</td><br>
<td>$print->;Studno</td><br>
<td>$print->;Title $print-&gt;Firstname $print-&gt;Lastname</td><br>
<td style="font-style: italic;"><center>PRIVATE</center></td><br>
<td><center><a href="$print->Linkedin" target="_blank" rel="noopener 
noreferrer"><u>Click Here</u></a></center></td><br>
<td style="font-style: italic;"><center>PRIVATE</center></td><br>
<td><center>$print->;Email</center></td><br>
<td>$print->;Nationality</td><br>
<td>$print->;City</td><br>
<td>$print->;Country</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Table and data wont appear do it have a problem in my code?

this is the other code that i tried but the data wont appear also

```
<?php global $wpdb; $table_name = $wpdb wp_ ."sheet1";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE Course='Filipino' ORDER BY Lastname"; 
<br>$result = $wpdb->   ;get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

<p>foreach ( $result as $print )<br>{<br>echo"</p>
<p>";</p>
<p>if ($print-&gt;Linkedin==null)<br>{<br>echo"</p>
<p>";<br>}else<br>{<br>echo"</p>
<p>";<br>}</p>
<p>if ($print-&gt;Email==null)<br>{<br>echo"</p>
<p>";<br>}else<br>{<br>echo"</p>
<p>";<br>}</p>
<p>echo"</p>
<p>";<br>}<br>?>;</p> ?>

<table id="passers_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><center>Course</center></th>
<th><center>Student Number</center></th>
<th><center>Name</center></th>
<th><center>LinkedIn Account</center></th>
<th><center>Email Address</center></th>
<th><center>Nationality</center></th>
<th><center>City</center></th>
<th><center>Country</center></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>$print->;Course</td><br>
<td>$print->;Studno</td><br>
<td>$print->;Title $print-&gt;Firstname $print-&gt;Lastname</td><br>
<td style="font-style: italic;"><center>PRIVATE</center></td><br>
<td><center><a href="$print->Linkedin" target="_blank" rel="noopener 
noreferrer"><u>Click Here</u></a></center></td><br>
<td style="font-style: italic;"><center>PRIVATE</center></td><br>
<td><center>$print->;Email</center></td><br>
<td>$print->;Nationality</td><br>
<td>$print->;City</td><br>
<td>$print->;Country</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i put it on the wp-login in the page where should the table and the data should appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please check below code and let me know if its not working. can i know which file you add this code ?

```
<?php    
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."sheet1";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE Course ='Filipino' ORDER BY Lastname";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
?>
<!-- Data should be appear in this table-->
<table id="passers_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><center>Course</center></th>
<th><center>Student Number</center></th>
<th><center>Name</center></th>
<th><center>LinkedIn Account</center></th>
<th><center>Email Address</center></th>
<th><center>Nationality</center></th>
<th><center>City</center></th>
<th><center>Country</center></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php 
foreach($results as $print){ 
?>
<td><?php echo $print->Course;?></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->Studno;?></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->Title.' '.$print->Firstname.' '.$print->Lastname;?></td><br>
<td style="font-style: italic;"><center>PRIVATE</center></td><br>
<td><center><a href="<?php echo $print->Linkedin;?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener 
noreferrer"><u>Click Here</u></a></center></td><br>
<td style="font-style: italic;"><center>PRIVATE</center></td><br>
<td><center><?php echo $print->Email;?></center></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->Nationality;?></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->City;?></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->Country;?></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello the table is working but the data wont display. im adding this to the page that the data will appear.

Comment: Ok so can you please add
print_r($results); and check you get data or not ?

Comment: where do i put the print_r($results);

Comment: Under this line
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

Comment: it still wont print the data but it have an "array ()" above the table

Comment: if its just print array() that means no data return when query execute so please check your table have valid data if yes then check table name and other column name which specified in where clause. Also if possible can you please share your database table screenshot here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
<?php    
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb wp_ ."sheet1";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE Course='Filipino' ORDER BY Lastname";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql);
?>

//Data should be appear in this table
<table id="passers_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><center>Course</center></th>
<th><center>Student Number</center></th>
<th><center>Name</center></th>
<th><center>LinkedIn Account</center></th>
<th><center>Email Address</center></th>
<th><center>Nationality</center></th>
<th><center>City</center></th>
<th><center>Country</center></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php foreach($results as $print-> )
{ ?>
<td><?php echo $print->Course;?></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->Studno;?></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->Title;.$print->Firstname.$print->Lastname;?></td><br>
<td style="font-style: italic;"><center>PRIVATE</center></td><br>
<td><center><a href="<?php echo $print->Linkedin;?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener 
noreferrer"><u>Click Here</u></a></center></td><br>
<td style="font-style: italic;"><center>PRIVATE</center></td><br>
<td><center><?php echo $print->Email;?></center></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->Nationality;?></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->City;?></td><br>
<td><?php echo $print->Country;?></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```